# Wolfram Alpha and Wolfram Engine produce different Laplace transforms

Tags: wolfram-cloud, integral-transforms, free-wolfram-engine

Consider the following Laplace transform:

$$\mathcal{L}\{\dfrac{\sin{2x}}{x}\}$$

To calculate it, I'd write `LaplaceTransform[Sin[2 x] / x, x, p]` into both Wolfram Alpha and WolframScript (for the command-line). WolframScript returns `ArcTan[2 / p]`, whereas Wolfram Alpha gives `(Pi - 2 ArcTan[p / 2]) / 2`. Although the two results appear different, plotting the functions shows they are actually equal for $p \gt 0$.

Performing the calculations by hand, I can arrive at the second answer.

How can I get WolframScript (or Wolfram Cloud) to produce the result of Wolfram Alpha?
I'm asking this because:

1. That's what I reached by hand.
2. That's what we usually want, since the result of a Laplace transform is expected to be valid for $p > 0$, not negative values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FullSimplify[ArcTan[2/p] - (Pi - 2 ArcTan[p/2])/2,  Assumptions -> p > 0]
```

> `0`

Comment: This relation can be analytically extended from the positive ray to  certain domains in the complex plane.

Comment: This result was already included in the question: "plotting the functions shows they are actually equal for p>0". What about the case of $p\leq 0$?

Comment: @MarkoB: First, a plot is a plausible reasoning, not a proof. Second, the case of `p<0` is of needless for `InverseFourierTransform` (see the documentation).  Third, up to Maple `FunctionAdvisor(branch_cuts, arctan(2/p)-(Pi-2*arctan((1/2)*p))*(1/2), plot = 2.)`, there are  branch cuts along the imaginary axis except the origin.

Comment: How can I get WolframScript to produce `(Pi - 2 ArcTan[p / 2]) / 2`? Isn't this the viable answer we are looking for, as $p$ is almost always assumed to be at least positive in a Laplace transform?

Comment: @MehrshadKhansarian: Don't know it. `Integrate[Sin[2 x]/x*Exp[-p*x], {x, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> p > 0]` results in `ArcTan[2/p]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] := Sin[2 x]/x

lt = LaplaceTransform[f[x], x, p]

(* ArcTan[2/p] *)
```

Taking the inverse,

```
f[x] == InverseLaplaceTransform[lt, p, x]

(* True *)
```

Whereas using [`WolframAlpha`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframAlpha.html)

```
lt2 = WolframAlpha[
   "LaplaceTransform[Sin[2 x]/x, x, p]", {{"Result", 1}, "ComputableData"}] //
   ReleaseHold

(* 1/2 (π - 2 ArcTan[p/2]) *)
```

Again taking the inverse,

```
ilt = InverseLaplaceTransform[lt2, p, x]

(* 1/2 (π DiracDelta[x] - 2 (1/2 π DiracDelta[x] - Sin[2 x]/x)) *)
```

**EDIT:** As pointed out by user64494 in a comment, [`Expand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Expand.html) simplifies the inverse

```
f[x] == ilt // Expand

(* True *)
```

Comment: `Expand[1/
   2 (\[Pi] DiracDelta[x] - 2 (1/2 \[Pi] DiracDelta[x] - Sin[2 x]/x))]` results in `Sin[2 x]/x`. In view of it your claim "To get the original function the DiracDelta must be eliminated" 
 seems very strange.

Comment: @user64494 - corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I, myself, could reach an explanation as to why Wolfram Engine has given such a result, thanks to the answer posted by @user64494.

Consider the following identity:
$$\cot^{-1}{x} = \dfrac{\pi}{2} - tan^{-1}{x}$$

Using the above, $\dfrac{\pi}{2} - tan^{-1}{\dfrac{p}{2}}$, the answer given by Wolfram Alpha and calculated by hand, can be written as $\cot^{-1}{\dfrac{p}{2}}$, which is in turn equal to $\tan^{-1}{\dfrac{2}{p}}$, whenever $p \gt 0$.

Comment: Your answer duplicates one already given.